# Tmux maps 2 Different Keys as the Same One Even If Unbound

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, configuration, tmux, keyboard-layout

I just configured my key bind for the `previous-window` command in Tmux to `Ctrl-[`. When I did this, I noticed that my `Escape` assumed the same behavior as `Ctrl-[` command. In other words, the `Escape` key also started changing to the previous window when I pressed it. This is very problematic because when I am editing in vim, for example, I am not able to go to normal mode, because Tmux is trying to change to the previous window instead.

I have already tried to unbind all the previous Tmux key binds, by putting `unbind-key -a` (I included my config file at the bottom as well) at the top of my Tmux config file. I have also tried to unbind the `Escape` key individually but also didn't work. After that I tried swapping the line `bind-key -n C-[ previous-window` to `bind-key -n Escape previous-window` to check if the reverse was true. To no surprise, even when the escape key was bound to change to the previous window, by pressing `Ctrl-[` it also still worked. Finally I checked if my keyboard layout is correct in the system settings, and there is also no problem there... Note that I always restarted Tmux with `source-file ~/.tmux.conf` after I changed anything in the config file.

At this point, My only guess is that Tmux sees the combination of `Ctrl-[` the same as the `Escape` key, which I find very confusing. If that is the case, I would have no idea how or where to go to fix it.

Here is my .tmux.conf file (most of it is probably unnecessary, but I included it anyway to be sure):

```
unbind-key -a

## Use default gnome terminal PS1
set-option -g default-command bash
# remap prefix from 'C-b' to 'C-a'
unbind Escape
unbind C-b
set-option -g prefix C-a
bind-key C-a send-prefix

# split panes using | and -
bind -n C-\\ split-window -h
bind -n C-_ split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %

# Create new window with ctrl+w and unbind previous commands 
bind-key -n C-n new-window
bind-key -n C-] next-window
bind-key -n C-[ previous-window
unbind &
unbind c
# unbind C-p

# Resize panes using alt and vim commands
bind -n M-h resize-pane -L 5
bind -n M-j resize-pane -D 5
bind -n M-k resize-pane -U 5
bind -n M-l resize-pane -R 5

# Unbind previous pane resize commands
unbind C-Left
unbind C-Right
unbind C-Up
unbind C-Down

# Reload tmux configuration with prefix (Ctrl+A) and r
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "~/.tmux.conf reloaded"

# switch panes using Alt-arrow without prefix
bind -n C-h select-pane -L
bind -n C-l select-pane -R
bind -n C-k select-pane -U
bind -n C-j select-pane -D

# Keys for ending sessions and windows etc.
bind -n C-w kill-window
bind -n C-q kill-server
# bind -n C-e kill-pane

# Enable mouse mode (tmux 2.1 and above)
set -g mouse on
setw -g monitor-activity on
# don't rename windows automatically
set-option -g allow-rename off

# PLUGIN MANAGER

# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'

# Theme plugin
set -g @plugin 'jimeh/tmux-themepack'

# Theme to use
set -g @themepack 'powerline/default/blue'

# Enable tmux vi mode
# setw -g mode-keys vi

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run -b '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

I would appreciate all the help and thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: "Tmux sees the combination of `Ctrl-[` the same as the `Escape` key, which I find very confusing. If that is the case, I would have no idea how or where to go to fix it." – In terminal this is [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esc_key) and there is nothing to fix. Do you want to differentiate the keys in a GUI terminal emulator? (what emulator?) or in virtual terminals like tty2?

Comment: Right, thank you very much, I didn't know that! I am simply using the GNOME terminal. Maybe there is a way to change in the .bashrc file?